# Android Application Issue, JSON reading RAW files

Tags: java, android, json

I feel I am very close to getting this working but so far no cigar. Can one of you wonderful developers give me some advice please :P

I have a *main activity* that provides a listview for the articles that are within the RAW folder, and I have a JSONparser class to get all this working.

My Main Activity as shown below is showing an error within this part of the try statement `List<News> news = businessParser.parseXML(this);` particularly the `parseXML`, which states change method to parse inputstream

```
public class Articles_Business extends FragmentActivity {
ListView businesslv;



//Is first called when the Activity is opened
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_artbusiness);


    //Implementing the listeners for Application Navigation
    Button btnbck=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbck);
    btnbck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Articles_Business.this, ArticlesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //Implementing the functionality for the XMLParsing of data to be used 
    // for users to view intended articles

    businesslv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.businesslst);

        try{
            BusinessJSONParser businessParser = new BusinessJSONParser();
            List<News> news = businessParser.parseXML(this);
            news = businessParser.parseXML(getAssets().open("businessnews"));
            ArrayAdapter<News> arrAdadter = new ArrayAdapter<News>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_artbusiness, news);
            businesslv.setAdapter(arrAdadter);


        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


}
```

but I have already stated an inputstream in the JSONparser
    public class BusinessJSONParser {

```
private static final String NEWS_ID = "newsId";
private static final String NEWS_TITLE = "newsTitle";
private static final String NEWS_CONTENT = "newsContent";

private News currNews = null;
private String currTag = null;
List<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();

public List<News> parseXML (InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException{
    try{
        XmlPullParserFactory xppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xppf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = xppf.newPullParser();

        //opening the correct xml file for the Business Class in a
        //Steaming method
        InputStream inputstream = inputStream.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.businessnews);
        xpp.setInput(inputstream, null);


        //parser sending events and the trigger response to open
        int i = xpp.getEventType();
        while (i != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (i == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                //System.out.println(xpp.getName());

                //Returning the text content in this event via the method
                //handleStartEvent()
                handleStartEvent (xpp.getName());
            } else if (i == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                currTag = null;
            } else if (i == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                //System.out.println(xpp.getName());

                //Returning the text content in this event via the method
                //parseContentEvent()
                parseContentEvent (xpp.getText());
            }
            i = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error" + e.getMessage(), currTag);

    }
    return news;
}




private void handleStartEvent(String name) {
    if (name.equals("news")) {
        currNews = new News();
        news.add(currNews);
    }else{
        currTag = name;
    }
}


private void parseContentEvent(String text) {
    String sText = text;
    if (currNews != null && currNews != null) {
        if (currNews.equals(NEWS_ID)) {
            Integer primary = Integer.parseInt(sText);
            currNews.setId(primary);
        }else if (currNews.equals(NEWS_TITLE)) {
            currNews.setTitle(sText);
        }else if (currNews.equals(NEWS_CONTENT)) {
            currNews.setContent(sText);
    }
}
}
```

}

and I dont think it is important but the .xml view for the activity just shows a 'back' button and a listview name 'businesslst'

I have been stuck for some time on this and will appreciate your input.
Thankyou

Comment: What is `businessParser.parseXML(this);` doing ? You are anyways re-initializing `news` in the second line.